# Django and solving the German Tank Problem

Tags: django, django-models

I want to make it impossible to find the exact number of users on a django-hosted site (known as the [German Tank Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem)). By default django assigns consecutive user ids, so presently anyone can create an account and then look through html/ajax requests for their own user id, which is the number of users at the moment that user signed up.

The codebase of the site in question is large enough, and user ids are used in ajax calls frequently enough, that the case-by-case solution is prohibitive (the solution being: finding every place user ids are used and using some hash instead). Is there a cleaner/faster way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to obfuscate the *total* number of signups, you can obfuscate that by fudging the user id value to a large number.  This won't prevent someone from interpolating your sign-up *rate* by creating multiple accounts at intervals and therefore having a clue at your real number, but your question was to prevent seeing the total number of users.

Answer (score -1):

Use a **[slug](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield)** instead of the row ID for the calls.

- If you use django generic Class Based Views (UpdateView, DetailView, etc...), the replacement should be easy since they take into account 'pk' or 'slug' url parameters to retrieve the object.
- It's human readable and SEO friendly.

[Slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) method helps to create them.